# Assigning popups/tooltips to circles in a static image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to JS and HTML so please bear with me.

I have a static image (in .jpg format) which is a kind of diagram containing 32 different circles.  They are each numbered 1 - 32  **however**  I am not able to manipulate the image in the sense that I cannot move the circles or change the numbers inside of them.

For the sake of simplicity, I have included an image below containing circles - this represents the image that I have.

[image]

My first objective is to make this image a thumbnail that, when clicked, expands to cover most of the page.

The following JQuery code serves this purpose:

```
  $("#thumbnailImage").click(function() {
                 $(this).attr('width', '400');
                  $(this).attr('height', '300');
```

I have inserted this into my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>

    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.15.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.15.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        #panel{ position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; z-index: 1010101; display: block; width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); color: white;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<div id = 'panel'>

<img id = "thumbnailImage" src="http://iskandarblue.github.io/mapbox/data/circles_page.jpg" width="350" height="250" alt="circles"/>'

</div>

<script>


mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaXNrYW5kYXJibHVlIiwiYSI6ImNpazE3MTJldjAzYzZ1Nm0wdXZnMGU2MGMifQ.i3E1_b9QXJS8xXuPy3OTcg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v8', //stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom

});

$("#thumbnailImage").click(function() {
   $(this).attr('width', '400');
    $(this).attr('height', '300');
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, the image expands in the wrong direction (it expands outward rather than inward), and does not collapse again when clicked twice. Is there an easy way to fix this ?

Now, once the image has expanded, I would like the user to be able to hover over a circle and see a popup text much like what the tipsy jQuery plugin does (see here): http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

I am not sure how to proceed or how to conceptualize the problem. What's the easiest way to assign pop-up functions to circles on a static image and how can these popups (or tooltips) be activated only when the image is in expanded mode? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered to use `<map>`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: Dear StackOverflow, please do my homework for me!